# Colored column in pdf output

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

I am trying to create a pdf with a `kable` table with a colored column. It shows fine in the console but when exported the colored column appears blank. Any suggestions?

```
    kable(resumen, 
      format = 'latex',
      col.names = c("Ruta",
                    "Viajes programados",
                    "Viajes extraídos",
                    "Porcentaje de viajes extraídos"),
      align = c('l', rep('c', 3))) %>% 
  kable_paper() %>% 
  kable_styling(full_width = T) %>% 
  column_spec(4, color = "white",
              background = spec_color(resumen$porcentaje[1:8], end = 0.8),
              bold = T)
```

[image: pdf output]

[image: Rstudio output]

Comment: The colors you're using are hex codes. However, Latex doesn't interpret a hex code as a color. You can either set up each color in Latex or you can save the table as an image. For example at the end of the code append `%>% as_image()`. This is a Kable function that is probably around for just this reason.